# Changing variable of integration $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_\limits{l\to\infty}\int_0^l\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\cos((t-x)\lambda)dtd\lambda$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the following limit:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_\limits{l\to\infty}\int_0^l\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\cos((t-x)\lambda)dtd\lambda$$

We know that $\int_0^l \cos((t-x)\lambda)d\lambda=\frac{\sin((t-x)l)}{t-x}$. Replacing $t$ by $x+u$, the limit above is equivalent to (that's what the book says)

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_\limits{l\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+u)\frac{\sin(lu)}{u}du$$.

Why is there $du$ instead of $d(x+u)$? By replacing $t$ by $x+u$ I understand plugging $x+u$ in every place where $t$ appeared. So $dt$ should become $d(x+u)$.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there $du$ instead of $d(x+u)$?

Here $x$ is a constant with respect to $u$, giving $\partial_u (x)=0 $ thus
$$
d(x+u)=\partial_u (x) \:dx+\partial_u (u)\:du=0\times dx+1\times du=du
$$ as announced.

Comment: I'm not sure where your equation comes from, but according to the definition of $df(u)$ I'm familiar with, $df(u)$ is defined as $f'(u) du$ where $f'(u)$ is a derivative with respect to $u$. In my case $f(u)=x+u$, $f'(u)=u$, and we have that $df(u)=du$. Much simpler, but do you think it is correct?

Comment: @user4205580 OK, if I follow you right, it is rather $f(u)=x+u$ giving $f'(u)=1$ leading to $d(x+u)=f'(u)du=du$. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean.